# Missing kernel modules on Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: ubuntu

For awhile ago I updated my system to install the latest updates (with apt). While the system was updating something happened and the system froze. I rebooted the system and managed to update the system.
However, there were some errors when installing kernel related packages (which  I didn't wrote down at the moment).
For the past days (2017-05) I tried to use bridge-utils package only to notice that I didn't have the bridge.ko module. I tried to reinstall the modules by using:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-78 linux-image-4.4.0-78 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78
```

which went well. After the update I could load the module. However, as soon as I rebooted the system the bridge module (among others) disappeared again.
My kernel is:

`uname -a
Linux mylinux01 4.4.0-78-lowlatency #99-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 27 16:46:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I see some other errors, like:

`sudo /lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load
Failed to find module 'ib_iser'`

or upon boot:

`failed to start load kernel modules`

or upon restart:

`failed unmounting /lib/modules`

What could be the problem? How can I persistently reinstall all the modules using apt?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: 16.04.4 hasn't been released yet. In May 2017 you must mean 14.04.4 or 16.04.2?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.4 was released in April 2016. My problem occurred in May 2017.

Comment: Do you mean **14.04.4**?

Comment: No, I mean 16.04.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem by booting from a live CD, mounting the / partition and manually copying the missing modules in /lib from a fresh Ubuntu install.